# Program wont run for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am writing a program which gets the sum of the square of each digit of a given number and keeps doing this for the new number until that number is either 42 or 1, this program does this for a range of numbers and finds how many number end up at 42 using this method.

when running my program in terminal it wont enter the for loop

I am new to coding so im sure its something simple.

I have played around using different variables and replacing the first for loop with a while but it still doesn't enter loop

```
  int a, b, x, n, y, z, m;

scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);

for (n=a; n > b; n++){
 m = n; 
 printf("entered for loop \n");
 while (m != 42) {
    y= m%10;
    x = x + (y*y);
    y = (m/10)%10;
    x = x + (y*y);
    y = (m/100)%10;
    x = x + (y*y);
    y = (m/1000)%10;
    x = x + (y*y);
    y = (m/10000)%10;
    x = x + (y*y);
    y = (m/100000);
    x = x + (y*y);

     if (x == 42){
      z = z + 1;

    }

    m = x;
 }
}

printf("%d\n", z);
```

so if someone inputs 2 and 10 i should get 7, i think there is still some fine tweaking to do to the code but im just rally stuck on this for loop

Comment: did you mean `n < b`?

Comment: Quick guess: `n > b` should be `n < b`

Comment: If someone enters 2 and 7, in the first loop iteration `n` and `a` will have value `2`,  `b` will have the value `7`, so `n > b` will be false, and the loop body never executes.   You probably intended the condition to be `n < b`, not `n > b`.   Accordingly, voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (n=a; n < b; n++)
```

n should be **less than** b in order to run the loop